# (Battery Status) What does CF mean? Why are there 2 batteries detected?

Tags: laptop, battery

When my laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad X230) is running on batteries, there's an added number in the power usage summary area that says, for example, "[CF 10]". What does 'CF' mean and what is the number for?
Also, recently, Battery Status started detecting 2 batteries but only showing 1 of them (my laptop only has 1 battery). When I press 'Switch', it says "Can't switch battery 1 (50)".

If anyone's wondering I mean the software found at http://users.rcn.com/tmtalpey/BattStat/ or https://sourceforge.net/projects/batt-stat/files/

Answer (score 1):

I have a ThinkPad X230 right here. There is only one battery (at the rear of the ThinkPad and at the bottom).  There is no front battery and no room for one.

The Lenovo battery manager (screen shot below) only shows one battery. Machine is running on batteries for this test.

The third party tools you pointed to above are not Lenovo Software and probably not detected the battery properly. There is just one battery.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what CF means?

Comment: There is no CF in the Lenovo Battery software. That is sometime from the third party battery software. There is no standard meaning for CF here . It can mean many things.

Comment: OK then. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I have completely confirmed all of the above with the X230 machine of mine (even by taking it apart to verfiy